# How can Apache use an existing IIS cert?

Tags: apache, ssl

I am new to this, but I've researched it a bit. I've seen other answers here that indicate I can share a cert between IIS and Apache, but I cannot figure out how to do so.
I have added an internal Apache based web server to an existing IIS server.  Everything worked fine when using port 8080 for the new server, but when I try to go to HTTPS and 8443, it fails and I have become very confused.
IIS mgr already shows certs and I don't know if I should attempt to export one of those or try to work with a new self signed one created with Keytool.  Neither seems to work.  I can connect, but but the client browser complains that  the server is untrusted.
I am wanting to eventually configure this new app for SSO since all users would be internal.  Do I have to pay for a trusted root cert just for internal stuff?   It seems like I should be able to use the existing certs the IIS server sees...

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use same certificate for both servers. You need to export the certificate and key from IIS and place it for apache server. You can find step by step instructions [here](https://support.servertastic.com/moving-ssl-certificate-from-iis-to-apache/).

Using the same certificate for number of servers will not cause any problems.

Comment: Thank you vaibhav, that looks pretty straightforward.  Now I just have to get OpenSSL.